# How do I add a global template in all MediaWiki pages?

Tags: mediawiki

I want to add a piece of wiki markup to all MediaWiki pages (exiting and future ones).

This piece of wiki  markup code doesn't have to be part of the page body because I do not want people to modify it.

How can I obtain this?

Details:  I am using the FB-Connect extension to enable Facebook authentication and comments but it looks that, in order to enable comments for all pages I have to append `<fb:comments></fb:comments>` to each page. I do not want to end-up editing each wiki page.

Answer (score 2):

I know I'm late, but just in case you haven't figured this out yet, there's a useful feature on Mediawiki ([Sitenotice](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Interface/Sitenotice)) that lets you display defined text at the top of all wiki pages. This should help with your situation.

Answer (score 1):

I put my facebook like buttons into skins/Vector.php. Search for footer. I describe it here: http://www.linuxintro.org/wiki/Mediawiki#FaceBook_like_buttons

Answer (score 0):

You could write a small [MediaWiki extension](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual%3aDeveloping_extensions) that uses a [hook](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual%3aHooks) to execute a function that modifies the page output after the article content has already been parsed and insert the comment area where you want.

Based on line 72 [here](http://fbconnect4mw.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/fbconnect4mw/trunk/Facebook/FacebookXFBML.php?revision=404&view=markup), it looks like all FB-Connect does when you put `<fb:comments></fb:comments>`in the article text is cause the same thing to be outputted in the HTML, and everything else is probably handled by javascript(s) that FB-Connect includes by default.  So, you can simply use the [SkinAfterContent](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual%3aHooks/SkinAfterContent) hook if you want the comment box to appear below the content box (a good example of this is Semantic MediaWiki's [Factbox](http://semantic-mediawiki.org/wiki/Help%3aBrowsing_interfaces#The_factbox) - [example](http://smwforum.ontoprise.com/smwforum/index.php/Help%3aActivating_the_factbox)) .  If you want the comment box to appear within the article content or especially at a specific place within the article content, then you need one of the page rendering hooks, possibly [ParserAfterTidy](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual%3aHooks/ParserAfterTidy), though I'm not sure.

If you need the hooked function to output a template, or other mediawiki markup, then it's possible to more or less pass some markup and the Page object to a Parser and get the resulting html text.